# MVC select dropdown then update and display string

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, dropdown

So what I would like to do is have a drop down list:

```
<div class="form-control">
    <div class="row">
        <p>This is a question:</p>
        <select id="Question1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
// Check answer button
</div>
<div>
// Display results
</div>
```

The user selects an option from the drop down list.

They then click a button called "Check answer."

If the answer is correct I want to display one message and if it's wrong display another.

I was able to achieve this in Blazor really easily in an @code{} section and just call the method from the html but I have no idea how to replicate this in MVC. Do I really need a model for this to work? Couldn't I just pass the value from the view to the controller, have the controller evaluate, and return a string to the view?

It's a static update so I'm sure I'll need an HttpPost method for returning the string I'm just not sure where to start.

What is the most simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the question need to be checked on the server or can this happen on the client?

Comment: @timothyclifford this is going to be a server side only application, which is why I originally considered Blazor but found out our current servers won't support Blazor at the moment and had to switch to MVC.

Comment: You can use Jquery (or simple javascript) to post the selected answer to the mvc controller (serverside) check the answer and use a viewbag to display the results in your view (cshtml page). I can give you a full example if you'd like

Comment: The short answer is to embed some Javascript / JQuery into your page on initial render, expose some API endpoints on your server, and use AJAX calls to get what you need. Not sure how familiar you are with AJAX, but it it might be the way to go.

Comment: @Dkar I had a feeling I'd end up needing to use Javascript in some form. If you had a simple example I would be very appreciative!

Comment: @NikP It looks like Dkar has a solution using simple Javascript, the page doesn't need to be dynamic and I don't know basically anything about AJAX so I'm going to avoid it if possible for the time being.

Comment: You can avoid javascript, use a simple Model  and just submit it. I will try to provide both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a simple controller. I am using the default HomeController and index.cshtml view.

Add the following method to your controller

```
public string CheckAnswer(string selectedAnswer)
{
    //Here you can check the answer and set a message.
    var message = (selectedAnswer == "1") ? "Correct Answer" : "Wrong Answer"
    return message
}
```

Inside your view (index.cshtml) add the following. I' ve also used some bootstrap css but you can ignore it

```
<form method="post" id="formQuestion" action="@Url.Action("CheckAnswer","Home")">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-control">
            <div class="row">
                <p>This is a question:</p>
                <select id="Question1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btnsubmit">Submit Answer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 answerResult">

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#formQuestion").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log($('#Question1').val())
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/CheckAnswer",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { "selectedAnswer": $('#Question1').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(".answerResult").html(data);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

The script will post the answer selected to the controller CheckAnswer method and whatever is returned will be displayed inside answerResult container DIV. This is very basic and off course you can improve it.